# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript code here that uses JQuery to create a class and to use class functions then.

```
function sample(a, b)
{
    var id = a;
    var img_src = b;

    this.getId = function()
    {
        return id;
    };

    this.move = function(pTop, pLeft)
    {
        var p = $(this).position();
        var mov_top = p.top + pTop;
        var mov_left = p.left + pLeft;
        $(this).animate({
            top: mov_top,
            left: mov_left
        });
    }
}
```

And I am calling it when clicking a button :

```
<button onclick="create(3);">Click me :D</button>

<script>            
    function create(id)
    {
        var mySample = new sample(id, 'url');
        mySample.move(50, 50);
    }   
</script>
```

And this returns me the error TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a but I don't see where it comes from...

Do anyone has an idea?

Comment: You should be calling mySample.move right?

Comment: What is `monSprite` ?

Comment: Probable `monSprite`/`mySample` typo aside, the `this` reference within `move` will refer to the `sample` function, not any element in the DOM, hence I'm not sure what you're expecting `position()` or any of the other jQuery methods to return.

Comment: monSprite is not anymore, this is mySample, that's right, and I just would like to have my button to move when I click on it (it's for testing purposes)

Comment: By the way, if the this reference within move() were wrong, then getId() should be wrong too, but getIt() is working.

Comment: @Avada Try adding `console.log(this)` within `this.move` to determine if it is an `DOM` element or not a `DOM` element

Comment: You should make it more clear what you all want to happen after the button is pushed...

Comment: @guest271314 In the log, I get  sprite { getId=function(),  move=function()}

Comment: @Avada Which `DOM` element is expected to be `this` within `this.move` ?

Comment: By writing this, I expect the button to be the selected element for the this.move() and so for the this.animate()

Comment: @Avada Try substituting passing `this` to `create()` at `onclick` , which should be `a` variable : `button` element at `sample()` ; setting `position` of `button` element; see post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `this` to `create()` instead of `3` which should be `a` within `sample()` , setting `button` `css` `position` to `relative`

```js
function sample(a, b)
{
    var id = a;
    var img_src = b;

    this.getId = function()
    {
        return id;
    };

    this.move = function(pTop, pLeft)
    {
        var p = $(a).position();
        var mov_top = p.top + pTop;
        var mov_left = p.left + pLeft;
        $(a).animate({
            top: mov_top,
            left: mov_left
        });
    }
}
```

```css
button {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button onclick="create(this);">Click me :D</button>

<script>            
    function create(id)
    {
        var mySample = new sample(id, 'url');
        mySample.move(50, 50);
    }   
</script>
```